# List rows which column value is not unique in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where some of the SongIds are repeated. I would like to extract those rows which have the repetition. Any idea how? Tried:

```
dfB[dfB.SongId.duplicated()]
```

But didn't work well.

This is an example of my dataframe. SongId 0, 10 and 16 are repeated in this example:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

try this,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Song ID":[0,0,1,3,1,4,5],'ArtistID':[12,13,34,1,21,43,22]})
print df[df.duplicated(subset=['Song ID'],keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
   Song ID  value
0        0     12
1        0     13
2        1     34
4        1     21
```